# Mapbox API: How do I get a list of addresses under a given postal code?

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

As in the question - I have a given zip code and I need to get a list of addresses with Mapbox API

After request for the endpoint below:

```js
`https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/${postcode}.json?types=postcode&access_token=${mapboxToken}`
```

I got the following response:

```
[
   {
      "id":"postcode.17660822408923720",
      "type":"Feature",
      "place_type":[
         "postcode"
      ],
      "relevance":1,
      "properties":{
         
      },
      "text":"HP1 3EN",
      "place_name":"HP1 3EN, Hemel Hempstead, Hertfordshire, England, United Kingdom",
      "matching_text":"HP13EN",
      "matching_place_name":"HP13EN, Hemel Hempstead, Hertfordshire, England, United Kingdom",
      "bbox":[
         -0.489006,
         51.760773,
         -0.487601,
         51.761635
      ],
      "center":[
         -0.488395,
         51.7610944
      ],
      "geometry":{
         "type":"Point",
         "coordinates":[
            -0.488395,
            51.7610944
         ]
      },
      "context":[
         {
            "id":"place.15727584894798730",
            "wikidata":"Q3532",
            "text":"Hemel Hempstead"
         },
         {
            "id":"district.8002140812776250",
            "wikidata":"Q3410",
            "text":"Hertfordshire"
         },
         {
            "id":"region.13483278848453920",
            "wikidata":"Q21",
            "short_code":"GB-ENG",
            "text":"England"
         },
         {
            "id":"country.12405201072814600",
            "wikidata":"Q145",
            "short_code":"gb",
            "text":"United Kingdom"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

In this response, there is nothing about the addresses under the given zip code.

When I specify the 'address' type in the URL query, it gets an empty array as a response.

```js
`https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/${postcode}.json?types=address&access_token=${mapboxToken}`
```

I can't find help in the [Mapbox documentation](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/search/geocoding/?q=distance&size=n_10_n#forward-geocoding), can someone help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to get the list of every single address within a given zipcode? You can't do this with Mapbox.

I doubt you will find any geocoding service which allows you to do this.